# Permutation by cycle

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a function that permutes an array.

Whenever the `offset` is greater than zero, however, one of the elements doesn't get replaced by `A[i]` and I'm just left with the default initialized value. I can't seem to figure out where the problem is. The `fill` and `print` functions in the code are just functions that fill an array with random elements and print an array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "print.h"
#include "random.h"
#include <memory>
int* permute_by_cycle(int A[], int size)
{
    int dest;
    int* C = new int[size];
    int last = size - 1;
    int offset = random(0, last);
    std::cout << "offset = " << offset << std::endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        dest = i + offset;
        //std::cout << "dest = " << dest << "\tlast = " << last << std::endl;
        if(dest > last)
            dest -= last;
        C[dest] = A[i];

    }
    return C;
}
int main()
{
    int size = 18;
    int A[size];
    //int* B = new int[size];
    fill(A,size);
    print(A,size);
    int* B = permute_by_cycle(A, size);
    print(B,size);
    delete [] B;
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
41 65 31 41 19 15 72 11 78 69 37 23 29 63 75 4 5 49 
offset = 16
0 31 41 19 15 72 11 78 69 37 23 29 63 75 4 5 49 65
```

Comment: Have you tried `std::next_permutation`? Might be useful (unless you just want to implement the algorithm of course).

Comment: No I haven't. I was trying to implement the algorithm but I'll take a look at that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
    if(dest > last)
        dest -= last;
```

with:

```
    if(dest > last)
        dest -= size;
```

You should use the `modulo` operator to manage cyclic access. My preferred version would be :

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    C[(i+offset)%size] = A[i];
}
```

This way, you can delete `dest` and all associated error-prone lines :)